# ATI driver installation

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I am using ubuntu 14.04, kindly assist how to install drivers for my ATI Radeon graphics card [Mobility Radeon HD 5650/5750 / 6530M/6550M].

I read some documentation on the given site but I am not sure if I really need to do all this.

http://www.securethelock.com/2014/04/20/installing-configuring-amdati-drivers-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation in your link is for installing the closed source drivers. I have a HD5650 and it works just fine with the open source drivers. There is nothing you need to do since these are the default drivers on the system.

Normally the closed source driver should give better 3D support ( the open source drivers have come a long way and are pretty good at this point ) and better support for the latest graphics cards. In case of the HD5600 series I see absolutely no need to install closed source drivers.